# How to save color boxes into the local storage?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, local-storage, dom-events

I want to save these color div boxes to the local storage on submitting (input value will be added to the div box as a backgroundColor)
thanks in advance!!

```js
const
  container = document.querySelector('.save-boxes .container'),
  myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', addBox);

// Adding div element
function addBox(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inputVal = input.value; // value
    if(!inputVal) return;  

    let box = document.createElement('div');
    box.className = 'hex-bg';
    box.style.backgroundColor = input.value;

    // hex-text
    let hexText = document.createElement('div');
    hexText.classList.add('hex-text');
    hexText.textContent = input.value;

    box.appendChild(hexText); // append input text on div   

    container.appendChild(box); // apppend 'hex-bg' div
    box.addEventListener('click', remove);

    this.reset();
}

// removing element on click
function remove() {
    let parent = this.parentElement;
    parent.removeChild(this); 
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.hex-bg {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="#821ab9" autofocus autocomplete="off" maxlength="7">
    <button>add</button>
   </form>

<!-- color boxes added from javascript -->
<div class="save-boxes">
    <div class="container">

       <!-- the sample div will be added..
        <div class="hex-bg" style="background-color: #fc06cc;">
            <div class="hex-text">#fc06cc</div>
        </div>
        -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Example of how it works:

[image: Here is an example of result]

Comment: Have you tried just saving the hex values in the search bar under localStorage and then process them when you have to use them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? MDN has a pretty good primer on how to use the local storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API. And I am sure there are plenty of helper classes to find on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the background color hex codes in local storage and while re-visit, you can read the local Storage and re-draw the div boxes.

For more information on local Storage [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)